# Android Volley Library errors with different devices

Tags: android, android-volley

The application is using the Volley library to make simple GET requests, I send the APK to some people with different devices, that agreed to test the app. 10 out of 14 had great experience and were satisfied with how fast the requests were made. But the other 4 were unable to get the requests, receiving the error:

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

I don't have the pleasure of going in depth with actual debugging on their devices, because of physical distance.
That is why I'm posting this question to anyone that had similar problem with the library or these device models:
Alcatel one touch alpha 6032; QUART-P5000; ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 5036D;
**My AppController:**

```
public class AppController extends Application {
public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}


public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

**My Fragment class:**

```
public class RepertoireTab extends ListFragment {
private static final String URL = "http://example.com/?json=get_category_posts&slug=Repertoire&status=publish";   
ListView listView;
MovieAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    adapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item);

    StringRequest movieReq = new StringRequest(URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Wrap wrap = new Gson().fromJson(response, Wrap.class);
                    for (Post post : wrap.getPosts()) {
                        adapter.add(post);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                        
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.repertoire_tab, container, false);

    getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;

}
}
```

*I have even tried calling the asynchronous task(volley code) in an Activity in a different app, sent the apk file to the devices that were giving error, but  still the same issue.* **Again, working fine on other devices.**

Comment: Maybe it is to early in fragment lifecycle to execute volley task in onAttach. Try to move the volley code to onActivityCreated or onCreate(). See this link: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments

Comment: I have tried moving the asynchronous task in onActivityCreated method, but it's still not working on those specific devices, I really don't get it, how can an app work on some devices and not work at all on other.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems here is that you initializing ProgressBar in onCreateView() method but you are calling it in onAttach method which is before onCreateView(). Solution is to move your asynchronus task (volley code) in onActivityCreated() method. This is fragment lifecycle:[image]

If you want that your volley task is executed every time you are entering this fragment, put it in onResume() method.

Comment: I have tried with completely removing the ProgressBar, still not working.